# Polymer "DOM-Bind" update Binding

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, polymer

I've the following Code in My Index.html:

```
<body unresolved>
    <template is="dom-bind" id="app">
        <span>[[userContext.Name]]</span>
    </template>
    <script>
    (function(document) {
        'use strict';
         var app = document.querySelector('#app');
         app.userContext = { Name: "Test" };
    })(document);
    </script>
</body>
```

This works Ok!

But when I now Refresh the UserContext like this:

```
app.userContext = { Name: "Hallo" };
```

The Page does not get Updated

Is there a way to refresh the Bindings?

Comment: Try `app.set('userContext.Name', 'Test');`

Comment: `app.set('userContext', {"Name": "Test"});` should work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a Polymer data binding API method like `set`

```
app.set('userContext.Name', 'Test');
```

See also https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#set-path

Comment: I also can set the usercontext via app.set('userContext', context); the child variables refresh also!